# UIScrollView and UIButton touch up in side event conflict

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I hava a TableViewController, When I tap on a cell it pushed into a detail controller. On the detail controller, I have a scrollview and a UIButton on it. I want single tap on the scrollview to back to TableView and touch the UIButton to do other things.
In the detail controller:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(singleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Now, when I tap the scrollview it back to tableview, but when I tap the UIButton, It also back to tableview, How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I did the same, more or less, and do not have this problem. A difference may be that my buttons are not sub-views of the scroll area. (In the UI the content scrolls 'beneath' the button views.) 

Frankly I do not know how to fix your problem but I suggest a workaround. Why don't you add a UIButton that covers the full size of your scoll view. This is the next sub view of yoru scroll view and contains no visible content. Your button is then a subview to the large button. Doing so you don't need any guesture recoginzer.

You may get better suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

1. A simple suggestion to make the tap with two fingers rather than a single finger.
2. Subclass the scroll view and implement it's touches methods. If the touch area is the same as the button frame, return NO to the gesture delegate. Button will take the touch.